# Large white space after skrollr content - Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, skrollr

I have a simple scrolling page, based on [this guide](https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/). It seems to work fine, except in IE8 (I've included skrollr.ie.min.js) - it mostly works there too, but there's a large area of white space after the final slide. I'm initialising skrollr as in that guide, using forceHeight: false.

Is there anything else I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was merely a missing closing div tag, so user error - in all the more modern browsers (including IE9 even) this was 'overlooked', in IE8 it caused one slide's worth of white space at the end of the page.